# My first C# game in Unity (introducing playerprefs)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, there is a profit count which is controlled by the addMoney variable in my money script ex. profitcount = addMoney.

When I add the player pref regarding my addMoney Variable it defaults the profitCount to 0 when it should in fact be 1. This is my first game, so it could be be very easily a small thing that I have misunderstood or overlooked.

moneyCount

```
public class moneyCount : MonoBehaviour
{

    float timeTillAdd = 1;

    public int addMoney = 1;

    public int money;

    public Text txt;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money");
        addMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("addmoney");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("addmoney", addMoney);


        if (Time.time >= timeTillAdd)
        {
            money += addMoney;
            timeTillAdd++;

        }


        txt.text = money.ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money", money);



    }


}
```

profit count

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class profitCount : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int profitAmount;

    public GameObject moneyManagerObj;
    moneyCount mc;

    public Text txt;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()


    {
        mc = moneyManagerObj.GetComponent<moneyCount>();
       // profitAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("profitamount");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        profitAmount = mc.addMoney;
        txt.text = profitAmount.ToString();

      //  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("profitamount", profitAmount);

    }
}
```

shopManager

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int item1_cost = 50;
    public int item1_upgrade = 5;
    public int item1_tier = 1;
    public int item2_cost = 50;
    public int item2_upgrade = 5;
    public GameObject moneyManagerObj;
    moneyCount mc;

    public Text txt;
    public Text item1;
    public Text item1_text;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {


        mc = moneyManagerObj.GetComponent<moneyCount>();
        item1_cost = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Item1_cost");
        //item1_upgrade = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Item1_upgrade");
        item1_tier = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Item1_tier");


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        item1.text = item1_tier.ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item1_cost", item1_cost);
        //  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item1_upgrade", item1_upgrade);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item1_tier", item1_tier);

        if (item1_tier > 0)
        {



            item1_text.text = ("Upgrade");





        }


    }




    public void on_click()


    {


        {

            if (mc.money >= item1_cost)
            {




                mc.money -= item1_cost;
                mc.addMoney += item1_upgrade;
                item1_tier += 1;
                item1.text = item1_tier.ToString();
                item1_cost += 50 * item1_tier;


            }



        }
    }














}
```

Comment: Try to remove `addMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("addmoney");` from your `moneyCount`script. Then run it and tell here if it works

Comment: yes it works when I remove the player pref, that's the issue I'm having without it it starts at 1 and goes up as normal but when i add the player pref function it starts at zero and therefore is impossible to earn money in game

Comment: did you understand the issue?

Comment: @thirteen3054 you should formulate this out a bit and add it as an answer ;)

Comment: removing the player pref resolves the issue, but then the value won't save when the game is closed and reopened

Comment: you do know that `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("XXX");` has an overload like `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("XXX", 1);` which will default the value to 1 if the preference doesnt exist right?

Answer (score 3):

## Two things:

1. Don't use `PlayerPrefs` to store save data. It isn't meant for that. Its meant for saving player *preferences* such as volume, full screen mode, or input type. The file used by `PlayerPrefs` is *plain text* and can't support complex data types.
2. If no save data exists, the values read out are zero (at least from PlayerPrefs). You need to account for this and currently you are not. When you move to a different method of saving, you'll get other errors, like null pointers or file not founds. You have to determine if a save exists *and only if it does,* should you read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you were assigning default value to `addMoney` during initialization i.e `public int addMoney = 1;`

But then in your start you were again assigning it a value that has not been saved yet `addMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("addmoney");`

If you want to create a record do it like this `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("addmoney",addmoney);`

Comment: You do not need to set a preference before calling get on it, there is an overload of GetInt that allows you to specify a default.  thus removing the need to call SetInt before calling GetInt.

Comment: @Eddge What doesn't make this answer wrong ;) because the OPs mistake was overwriting the local start value with 0 before storing the correct value ;)